# Why does UriKind have Selection A : Selection B : Selection A | B

Tags: c#, uri

Why does `URIKind` have

`Absolute`, `Relative`, `RelativeOrAbsolute`.

Why not just always use `RelativeOrAbsolute` to prevent explosions in the code?

Answer (score 3):

Because downstream code might be expecting one or the other. For example, if your code is working with an absolute base URI of http://example.com/foo/, and you want users to enter the path to some resource, you want a relative URI. You wouldn't want them to enter http://afu.com/myname/home, because then when you tried to use the value that the user entered you'd end up with either 1) the wrong path; or 2) an error trying to create the URI "http://example.com/foo/htta://afu.com/myname/home".

The same kind of thing happens if you're expecting an absolute URI and somebody gives you a relative URI. If you don't have a defined base URI, then that relative URI isn't going to do you any good.

You'd be "preventing blowups in the code" at user input time, but making a worse problem for somebody else (perhaps you) to clean up later. The three values--absolute, relative, indeterminate--let you decide what is valid and allow you to reject bad data as soon as it's entered rather than later.

Comment: Right. It allows you to fail early- fail at the point where the bug occurs, rather than later. This is a good principle in general because a) you're more likely to have exceptions rather than potentially dangerous and silent bad behaviour and b) it makes debugging from a stack trace or whatever simpler, because you know where the actual fault occurred.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation of [UriKind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.urikind%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you will see:

> Defines the kinds of Uris for the Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(String,
>   UriKind) and several Uri.Uri methods.

It gives you the ability to distinguish between Absolute and Relative URI.

Now consider an example where you want user to enter only absolute URI and verify if it is well formed. Then you will do:

```
string inputUri = "/index.html)";
bool ifValid = Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(inputUri, UriKind.Absolute);
```

If there is only `RelativeOrAbsolute` then the above would return true.